# Create variable from non-consecutive variables using APPLY in R

Tags: r, apply

## Question

I am attempting to use the `apply()` function in R to create a new variable that sums several non-consecutive variables within my dataset.

The dataset is a dataframe with 40 variable & 1,000 observations. (I don't yet know how to represent this visually on StackOverflow.)

I am able to use this function to sum consecutive variables with this:

```
data$newvar <- apply(data[24:34], MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)
```

I would like to create a variable that sums 24 & 34, but not 24 through 33.

```
data$newvar <- apply(data[24,34], MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I receive the following error:

> dim(X) must have a positive length

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is data? A dataframe? [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP's code

```
data[24,34]
```

is selecting the element in the 24th row and 34th column instead of columns 24 and 34.  So, it is a `vector` with length 1.  Therefore, we get the error

> dim(X) must have a positive length

To select those columns, concatenate (`c`) it.

```
data[,c(24,34)]
```

If the original dataset is `data.frame`, the `,` is not needed

```
data[c(24,34)]
```

and then we can use `apply`

```
apply(data[c(24,34)], 1, FUN=sum)
```

But, this can be solved without using the loop.

```
rowSums(data[c(24,34)])
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. This fixed the problem.